# cordova capture audio , and get file path

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, phonegap, capture

I have a problem please help me,
I have a sound recording page without interface, but I can not know which audio track was recorded,
Is there a way to know the track of a recorded sound or not?
I just want the audio track to play the audio track

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
   
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        // Wait for Cordova to load      
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  // PhoneGap is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            recordAudio();
        }
        // Record audio
        // 
        function recordAudio() {
            var srcd = "myrecording" + Math.random() + ".wav";
            var mediaRec = new Media(srcd, onSuccess, onError);
            // Record audio
            mediaRec.startRecord();
            // Stop recording after 10 sec
            var recTime = 0;
            var recInterval = setInterval(function () {
                recTime = recTime + 1;
                setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
                if (recTime >= 10) {
                    clearInterval(recInterval);
                    mediaRec.stopRecord();
     }
    }, 1000);
  }
  
   function onSuccess() {

            alert('Uploaded Successfully');
        }
  
        // onError Callback 
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Set audio position
        // 
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <button onclick="recordAudio()">Record Audio</button>    
    <p id="media">Recording audio...</p>
    <p id="audio_position"></p>
    <br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say without interface but page has a button. onError and onSuccess functions give you info about status of records. Prevent multiple press to button and track latest "srcd" variable then set status of "srcd" according to error and success functions.

Comment: but how  i do that ? help

Comment: HHELP PLEASE , GOD

Comment: GOD , HELP ME .....